# WebGUI with Blazor / C# .. can blazor realize Windows Forms PictureBox class?

Tags: c#, frontend, blazor, picturebox

We try to realize a web-based UI using blazor. To make the first steps, we
are trying to do the following:

- Design a basic frontend
- Create button for connection with a (local) mySQL database
- Draw heatmap of stored positions (data
  visualization/picturebox)

Can blazor handle the Windows Forms PictureBox class? Or how do you show images which are generated by an internal function using blazor?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using blazor web assembly or server side?  If the former, you are not going  to be able to connect to the MySQL database without a server to act as an intermediary. 
And no, you cannot use a WinForms class like picture box in a blazor web app.

Comment: Blazor is rendered using HTML, which has `<img` and `<canvas` elements. Pick one.

Answer (score 0):

Images are displayed either adding an `<img>` tag or using a `<div>` tag with a css background image.

To add them dynamically, you'll need to use the tree builder:

```
@code
{    
  protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
  {
      base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
      builder.OpenElement(0, "img");
      builder.AddAttribute(1, "src", "/myawesomeimagefolder/myawesomeimage.png");
      builder.CloseComponent();
  }
}
```